# Get a list of users for whom mobile notifications has been enabled on Twitter

Tags: twitter

Is there a way using the Twitter API to get a list of users for whom mobile notifications has been enabled for a particular account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API does not make this information available.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the API, but this used to be manually available on the mobile setting page, but they got rid of that too.